# Pass or no by reference?

Tags: parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, d

I'm writing a `MyClassCollection`. It's an array,that will store a lot of instances of `MyClass`. The array is declared as the following: `MyClass[] myClassInstances;` that by `Add(MyClass ins)` method I store `ins` in `myClassInstances`.

My question is: should I pass it by reference? Will I get better performance? I do not really need a copy of it; I prefer to use the instantiated class (right?); or is it a useless effort to optimization (maybe of memory only?).

Here's my current code:

```
class foo { }

class foocollection {
  private foo[] foo_instances;
  public @property foo[] data() { return foo_instances; }
  public void add(foo f) {
     ++foo_instances.length;
      foo_instances[$-1] = f;
  }
}
```

Comment: `foo_instances ~= f` does the same as `++foo_instances; foo_instances[$-1] = f;`

Comment: @dav1d: Thank you. I will consider to use cat operator instead of. Actually, `++foo_instances;` that's a typo. I did mean `++foo_instances.length;`. I'm sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have isn't even legal code. You can't increment an array. If you want to append `f` to `foo_instances`, then use the append operator:

```
foo_instances ~= f;
```

As for passing by reference, I don't quite get what you're asking. *What* are you trying to pass by reference? The argument to `add`? i.e.

```
public void add(foo f) {...}
```

vs

```
public void add(ref foo f) {...}
```

The `ref` is pointless. You're not altering the class reference passed in, so there's no reason to use `ref`. That would just be confusing. And while you'd need to profile to be 100% certain what the performance implications are, I'd be very surprised if passing by `ref` were faster. Classes don't get copied when passing them to functions. They're reference types. So, it's the reference which get copied - not the object. It's basically a pointer (though I believe that it does have some extra type stuff in it so that it's slightly more than a pointer). Copying them is cheap. You shouldn't have to worry about the cost of passing a class to a function. If you were using a *struct*, it could make a difference, since structs are normally value types and are on the stack unless you explicitly put them on the heap, but for classes, it's a non-issue.

Regardless, if you have a performance question, the #1 thing to do is to profile your code. It's true that there are some things which are clearly more or less efficient than other things, but you often don't know for sure until you see what the compiler actually does, and the results can often be the opposite of what you expected. So, if you want to know about performance, profile your code.

Comment: That's a typo. I'm sorry! I did mean `++foo_instances.length;`

Comment: It's exactly what I am looking. In fact, I'm looking for it to do a possible *optimization*. I had in my mind that by using `ref` keyword, the compiler will not need do a copy of argument to function.  e.g, foo f = new foo(); method(f); where prototype is void method(ref foo f); I would only one copy of `f` in memory. Unlike if the method prototype is: method(foo f); I would two: the `f` instance that I did by hand, and that the compiler does copy.I can see now how it's unnecessary.